# Compile html with angular2

Tags: angular

I'm having a component that makes an http request in its `ngOnInit` function. This call retrieves the content of the page that can contains angular directives such as `routerLink` or even angular2 custom component.

I found the way to inject this content in a `div` (using the `innerHTML` property), however, the inserted content does not get compiled by "angular2" resulting in `routerLink` being just an attribute without effect. And of course, the components don't appear.

Is there a simple way to ask angular2 to compile the inserted HTML?

Comment: To create dynamic components, see these answers the solution is there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular/39773331#39773331

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand angular takes template `html` and generate `js` factory code from it. When component is loaded, there is no way to change specified template